# Windows Desktop VB.Net Apps Getting an error 1004 0x800A03EC reading Excel due to 0xC004F057 in Application Event log

Tags: excel, windows

We have several Windows Desktop Apps written in VB.2010 and VB.2017 that have been running for a long time at many customers.  Then last week Tues, Nov 13, 2018 we started getting customers emails and calls saying the apps are getting an error 1004/0x800A03EC. No app updates where made. Worked one day then stopped.

It doesn't fail here. Tried on 4 different systems. W7/Excel 2013, W10 w/Office 365/Excel 2016.

The failures have happened on W10, 7 and 2012 R2.

Apps are just reading the excel file.

Code
Code to initialize ws

```
ExcelAppObj = New Excel.Application

ExcelAppObj.Visible = pVisible
WB = ExcelAppObj.Workbooks.Open(pFFn, True)
WS = pWB.Worksheets(1)
Ss = "A" & Row & "." & ColNames(UsedColsSht) & Row + 1
Dim War as object = WS.Range(Ss).Value
```

In the Application Event log we found this warning
*Installation of the Proof of Purchase from the ACPI table failed. Error code:
0xC004F057*

Just 2 prior was
*The Software Protection service is starting.
Parameters:caller=EXCEL.EXE*

which to me indicates that some component in Windows does not think it is genuine. I know that on the system that got the error above both Windows 2012 R2 and Office are genuine.

I am sure this is a MS bug.  Can someone point me in the right direction and hopefully a MS fix??????

Thanks and Happy ThanksGiving!

Comment: So look at the updates that were applied to office in November, ie the 13th of November.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4461503/description-of-the-security-update-for-excel-2016-november-13-2018

Comment: I don't have access to my clients' machine but one told me that what was installed around that time was KB4467703 and KB4467697.  Those update were not installed on my systems which are up to date.

Even the client that did a system to get it working wants to get their system current again.

Another client uninstalled the last 2 updates (I don't know the numbers) but didn't want to reboot for fear of updates being re-installed again.

Comment: I looked at another client's application event log  and that excel warning (Installation of the Proof ofPurchase from the ACPI table failed. Error code ...:)is NOT there.  So my only lead is gone.

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem but not clear why.

As posted above our code was using a range value of

```
Ss = "A" & Row & "." & ColNames(UsedColsSht) & Row + 1
s = ws.Range(Ss).value
```

Note: that a period was used so the range was something like A1.C3
This continues to work in 7 of our 8 systems that we have seen but when we used this format in the excel screen we got a #Field! error.  This is a new Excel behavior.

Changing our apps to use a colon instead of a period solved the problem.
So the range is now

```
Ss = "A" & Row & "." & ColNames(UsedColsSht) & Row + 1
```

or A1:C3

Again it worked in most systems and that cannot be explained. There was nothing in the event logs and the original posting in the header was a false alarm.